Equivalence of triangulated categories defined by tilting objects
I asked this question on stack exchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4983535/equivalence-of-triangulated-categories-defined-by-tilting-objects), but got no responses, so I ask it here.
Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a $k$- linear triangulated category (i.e. a triangulated category whose Homs are k-vector spaces). Suppose we have a tilting object $T \in \mathcal{T}$. Recall, this means that $T$ classically generates $\mathcal{T}$ and Hom$(T, T[l]) = 0$ for all $l \neq 0$.
Define $A := End(T)$, the endomorphism algebra of $T$.
Then, if I understand correctly, there should be an equivalence
$\mathcal{T} \xrightarrow{\sim} D^{b}(A)$.
My question is that I am not sure what this equivalence should be, and whether one needs additional assumptions on the triangulated category $\mathcal{T}$?
For example, if $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{D}^{b}(R)$ is the bounded derived category over some ring, is the equivalence given by $\mathbb{R}Hom(T,-)$?
I read that maybe this has some connection with tilting theory (whatever that is!), and I am mainly interested in this question because I would like to ultimately understand the triangulated subcategories generated by exceptional objects (recall, strong exceptional sequences give tilting objects in any triangulated category).
Perhaps my question is stated more vaguely than I would like it to be, but I am looking for precise statements and proofs of these statements which I cannot find in the literature (any references would be much appreciated!)

Could you specify the meaning of "classically generates"? Note that smallest triangulated subcategory of $D^b(A)$ that contains $A$ is the homotopy category of finitely generated free $A$-modules, and this subcategory is often not equivalent to $D^b(A)$. Moreover, you probably need some enhancement for your category to define a "reasonable" $RHom$ (which appears to be a good idea).

@MikhailBondarko By classically generates, I mean the smallest thick subcategory of $\mathcal{T}$ containing T. For example, this is the definition used in `On the derived category of Grassmannians in
arbitrary characteristic' by Buchweitz et al.

If you use this definition then you can get any triangulated category between the homotopy category of finitely generated free A-modules and the homotopy category of finitely generated projective A-modules. Both of these can be smaller than $D^b(A)$.

Too long for a comment.
Is your interest genuinely about general abstract k-linear triangulated categories? If so, I believe the conclusion you want cannot occur in general. For example, see
Muro, Fernando; Schwede, Stefan; Strickland, Neil, Triangulated categories without models, Invent. Math. 170, No. 2, 231-241 (2007). ZBL1125.18009.
Recall that a triangulated category is said to be algebraic if it is triangulated equivalent to the stable category of a Frobenius category. Roughly, a Frobenius category is a category with injective and projective objects such that these two classes coincide. To obtain the stable category you then quotient out those maps which factor through an injective-projective object.
One can show this stable category has a triangulated structure. Derived categories of (dg-)modules are always of this form.The first half of what Muro, Schwede, and Strickland show is that there is an explicit example of a triangulated category which cannot be equivalent to an algebraic one.
Having said that, once you require your triangulated category to be algebraic you are in luck. Although as Mikhail Bondarko says in the comments you need to first define what you mean by $\mathbb{R}Hom$, and what you mean exactly by derived category $D^{b}(R)$ (or similar) but essentially your equivalence is indeed given by this functor.
Details of this you can find in
Keller, Bernhard, Deriving DG categories, Ann. Sci. Éc. Norm. Supér. (4) 27, No. 1, 63-102 (1994). ZBL0799.18007.
And a general survey in
Angeleri Hügel, Lidia (ed.); Happel, Dieter (ed.); Krause, Henning (ed.), Handbook of tilting theory., London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series 332. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-0-521-68045-5/pbk). viii, 472 p. (2007). ZBL1106.16300.
(Concretely, Keller's derived categories and tilting, the theorem right after 8.7 on the ArXiV version)
Hope this is of help.

Thank you for your detailed answer. This helps a lot.

I would only add that currently there exist many more examples of triangulated categories without models. I don't know whether they contain tilting objects, though.

I am confused: why is it the bounded derived category in place of the unbounded one?

@Z.M A priori in general there is no reason for it to be the bounded category, I'm just following along Sunny's proposed example where T=Db(R).

I am confused even in this sort of example. I am not sure how triangulated categories are different, but if it enriches to a stable $\infty$-category which is compactly generated by a single object, then by the Schwede–Shipley theorem, it is equivalent to the unbounded derived category.

IIRC both D(Ab) and Db(Ab) have unique $\infty$-enhancements for reasonable (Grothendieck?) abelian categories, so no issue in picking one language over the other (This is in Antieau's paper). The issue lies in what Mikhail's was commenting before, what is it understood by generation here? Schwede-Shipley mean smallest localizing subcategory (so arbitrary coproducts). Sunny's notion of classical generators asks for smallest thick subcat (so, closed under direct factors). These are related but different things, perhaps saying T=Perf(R) is less confusing? Mikhail's comments remain most precise.
